# How are perl's -T and -B implemented?

Tags: perl, ascii

What does perl's -T function really do? From the man page on perlfunc:

```
-T  File is an ASCII text file (heuristic guess).
-B  File is a "binary" file (opposite of -T).
```

Is the `-B` option simply equivalent to `! -T`, or is it simply an inversion of the heuristic, such that some of the time, a file may be true for both -B and -T. Does the heuristic have, say, a threshold for control characters? Does it ignore tabs, EOLs, EOFs and NULs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [same page:](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html)

> The -T and -B switches work as follows.
>
> The first block or so of the file is examined to see if it is valid UTF-8 that includes non-ASCII characters. If, so it's a -T file. Otherwise, that same portion of the file is examined for odd characters such as strange control codes or characters with the high bit set. If more than a third of the characters are strange, it's a -B file; otherwise it's a -T file. Also, any file containing a zero byte in the examined portion is considered a binary file. (If executed within the scope of a use locale which includes LC_CTYPE , odd characters are anything that isn't a printable nor space in the current locale.) If -T or -B is used on a filehandle, the current IO buffer is examined rather than the first block. Both -T and -B return true on an empty file, or a file at EOF when testing a filehandle. Because you have to read a file to do the -T test, on most occasions you want to use a -f against the file first, as in next unless -f $file && -T $file .

Comment: Maybe your manpage version is newer than mine (5.16.3) :) Thanks.

Comment: That text has been there since at least 5.8.8, though the wording has varied.

Comment: @ikegami nope, not in mine. Only two references to the options, and nothing explicative.

Comment: Here's the passage that came with 5.8.8 *and* 5.16.3: "The -T and -B switches work as follows. The first block or so of the file is examined for odd characters such as strange control codes or characters with the high bit set. If too many strange characters (>30%) are found, it's a -B file; otherwise it's a -T file. Also, any file containing null in the first block is considered a binary file.".